# Using an IF STATEMENT to compare dimensions and return statement - VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, nested-if

```
Sub Dimensions()

    Dim i As Integer

    LastRow = Sheets("Log").Range("C3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    For i = 3 To LastRow
        If Sheets("Log").Range("C" & i).Value <= "24 x 16.5 x 0.5" Then
        Sheets("Log").Range("I" & i).Value = "Letter"

        ElseIf (Sheets("Log").Range("C" & i).Value <= "35.3 x 25 x 2.5") And (Sheets("Log").Range("C" & i).Value > "24 x 16.5 x 0.5") Then
        Sheets("Log").Range("I" & i).Value = "Large Letter"

        ElseIf (Sheets("Log").Range("C" & i).Value <= "45 x 35 x 16") And (Sheets("Log").Range("C" & i).Value > "35.3 x 25 x 2.5") Then
        Sheets("Log").Range("I" & i).Value = "Small Parcel"

        Else
        Sheets("Log").Range("I" & i).Value = "Medium Parcel"

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have tried this code, but it seems this is more complicated than I had anticipated. Had a look around the posts and haven't had much luck in solving the issue. The output is wrong.

The code is suppose to do the following:

- if the given dimension is less than "24 x 16.5 x 0.5", then it should display the output result as "Letter".
- if the given dimension is less than "35.3 x 25 x 2.5", then it should display the output result as "Large Letter".
- if the given dimension is less than "45 x 35 x 16", then it should display the output result as "Small Parcel".

Anything bigger than the specified dimension should print out "Medium Parcel".

Any help with this is greatly appreciated, I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now :(

List of Dimensions:
[image: List of Dimentions]

Comment: no i am trying to compare the two sizes. for example, if "2.3 x 2.3 x 0.5" is less than "24 x 16.5 x 0.5" then the output result should be "Letter"

Comment: Why not just add an extra column to your dimensions table stating what category each one is, then do a `VLookup`.

Comment: vlookup would not work in this case, as i need to adjust the code to take into account the weight, that is the next step in my code. but i am struggling with the basics at the moment... 

if you see the image, you will be able to see what i mean XD

Comment: Are the cell values chosen from a picklist (and therefore you know all potential cell values that could exist) or are they user input in random format - e.g. can the user enter `23 x 30 x 2` which needs to be treated as larger than `24 x 16.5 x 0.5` but less than `35.3 x 25 x 2.5`?

Comment: yes, the user may enter 23x30x2 and the programme should treat it as larger than 24 x 16.5 x 0.5 but less than 35.3 x 25 x 2.5

Answer (score 0):

A nice challenge!

Try the following function:

```
Function LetterSize(s As String) As String
    'Break source string into the three dimensions
    Dim a() As String
    a = Split(s, "x") 
    'Convert to numeric values
    Dim d(1 To 3) As Double
    d(1) = CDbl(a(0))
    d(2) = CDbl(a(1))
    d(3) = CDbl(a(2))
    'Sort into ascending dimension size
    Dim dt As Double
    If d(1) > d(2) Then dt = d(1): d(1) = d(2): d(2) = dt
    If d(1) > d(3) Then dt = d(1): d(1) = d(3): d(3) = dt
    If d(2) > d(3) Then dt = d(2): d(2) = d(3): d(3) = dt
    Debug.Print d(1) & " x " & d(2) & " x " & d(3)

    'Determine category
    If d(1) <= 0.5 And d(2) <= 16.5 And d(3) <= 24 Then
        LetterSize = "Letter"
    ElseIf d(1) <= 2.5 And d(2) <= 25 And d(3) <= 35.3 Then
        LetterSize = "Large Letter"
    ElseIf d(1) <= 16 And d(2) <= 35 And d(3) <= 45 Then
        LetterSize = "Small Parcel"
    Else
        LetterSize = "Medium Parcel"
    End If
End Function
```

Use it in your loop as:

```
For i = 3 To LastRow
    Sheets("Log").Range("I" & i).Value = LetterSize(Sheets("Log").Range("C" & i).Value)
Next i
```

Comment: @ArsalanRana - Hmm - Is that on the very first record?  Or have some of the records been processed and it only crashes on one part-way through your data?

Comment: Thankyou so much! I have adjusted the code accordingly and it works like a charm! now I am going to attempt to add to your hard work by implementing the weight property to take into account =D